# How can I regroup multiple tlogRow in talend to one file where I can see all my rows?

Tags: json, mongodb, postgresql, etl, talend

I am working on a MongoDB database ETL, I need to prosses the data and move it to the PostgreSQL database, I used the tExtractJson in talent to extract all the documents and subdocuments but I am having a problem in regrouping all the rows into one output so that I can load my tables in Postgres DB.

to load only one table I need information from multiple tlogRows

I tried a tmap but it requires a main component and other are lookup one

Comment: You'll have to elaborate exactly what your problem is, what you have tried so far, and how those results aren't what you need

Comment: I tried a tmap but id doesn't work on different rows it wors only on inputs

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using a tBufferOutput in the first job, and did the same thing once again on a second job and used a tInputBuffer to recover the result of the first job.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0JFT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/427uT.png)